# Android query multiple columns get count

Tags: android, sqlite, select, group-by, multiple-columns

I am trying to query a table and get a result that will show all the fruit entries in a table that has 10 columns. Here is the table structure.

```
    Table 1
    Name          Col2    Col3      ...    Col11
    Apple Pie     Apple   Cinnamon  ...    Flour
    Sugar Cookie  Flour   Sugar     ...    Vanilla
```

I have tried this sql query and the result is close to what I am looking for.

```
    SELECT
    Col2 as Flavor, COUNT(*)
    FROM
    table 1
    group by Flavor
```

What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to get the other 9 columns in the query. The expected result should be.

```
    Flavor      Count
    Apple       1
    Cinnamon    1
    Flour       2
    Sugar       1
    Vanilla     1
```

Thanks for all the comments that steered me in the right direction. Can anyone help with figuring this out?

Comment: i would say it's better to get that info before populating the listview, and create a list of custom object `Entry`, say it has {string value="", int count=0} and pass `List<Entry>` to the adapter.

Comment: @MrEd, if you are getting count from database, then you should change the approach. First of all get all count of items from database by using group and count and then populate your listview using custom adapter.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question after reading the comments and realizing that I am going in the wrong direction. So hopefully, it will make more sense.

Comment: Look up how GROUP BY works.

Comment: Thanks CL, that got me closer and helped me realize what I am after. But did not provide the solution. I have modified by question hope this can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again for all your help! The comments lead me to the right answer. Here is the solution.

```
    SELECT SUM(Output.count),Output.attr 
    FROM
    (
    SELECT COUNT(flv1name) AS count,flv1name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv1name 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv2name) AS count,flv2name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv2name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv3name) AS count,flv3name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv3name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv4name) AS count,flv4name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv4name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv5name) AS count,flv5name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv5name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv6name) AS count,flv6name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv6name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv7name) AS count,flv7name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv7name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv8name) AS count,flv8name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv8name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv9name) AS count,flv9name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv9name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(flv10name) AS count,flv10name AS attr FROM recipes GROUP BY flv10name) AS Output

    GROUP BY attr
```

This displays the result as

```
    SUM.Output.Count     attr
    1                    Apple
    1                    Cinnamon
    2                    Flour
    1                    Sugar
    1                    Vanilla
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the occurrence of an item in the list as follows :

```
import java.util.Collections;

// count the occurrence of item one in the list
int itemOneCount =  Collections.frequency(listitem,"item one");
```

Comment: i don't think OP wants to count within the list itself, OP says something about a table, maybe frequency is counted from a database?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question after reading the comments and realizing that I am going in the wrong direction. So hopefully, it will make more sense.